# How to prevent XDocument.Parse throwing XmlException if an element contains an escaped (invalid) character &#x1D;

Tags: c#, xml

I have this XML string

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<myxml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="somenamespace">
  <date>202105170526</date>
  <internalref>3</internalref>
  <platform>&#x1D;X</platform>
</myxml>
```

In the platform element there is an escaped character &#x1d (0x1D which is an invalid character in XML).

When calling

```
XDocument.Parse
```

an `XmlException` is thrown

`'', hexadecimal value 0x1D, is an invalid character. Line 48, position 30.`

Because the invalid character is escaped (using [character references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML#Character_references)?) I would expect XDocument to parse the string.

**Questions**

1. Why does XDocument throw XmlException?
2. How to prevent XDocument from throwing XmlException?

Comment: Why is that in your XML in the first place?  I'd suggest removing it before parsing.

Comment: no amount of fixing your parser to be soft and lenient can ever beat _having valid input_. that's where you'll have to apply the fix: in the code that generated this XML in the first place.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann And what if the invalid XML comes from somewhere (another product) that you cannot fix?

Comment: @tipa step one: non-technical solutions. try to enforce other teams to adhere the standards. step two: implement a workaround that treats the _string_ before passing it off to the xml parser. and making sure it doesn't over-correct and damage valid input.